# Injective projection of subtree onto maximal subtree

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, cayley-graphs

So I am writing my master thesis and I came across proposition 1.12 on Oleg Bogopolski's book "*Introduction to group theory*". That proposition states that;

"Let G be a group acting on a connected graph X without inversion of edges. For any subtree T' of the factor graph G\X there exists a subtree T in X such that $p_T:T\to T'$ is an isomorphism".

The proof uses Zorn's lemma on the set of subtrees of X that project injectively into T'. I found similar arguments on a number of books and notes (including Serre's "Trees") and no one actually proves that this set is non-empty.

At first I was misled to say "yes, at least it contains the edges that project onto $T'$" which I believe is wrong and now I will elaborate why I believe that;

Say, an edge e is projected injectively onto T'. Then $ge\in\mathcal{O}(e)$ ($\mathcal{O}$=orbit) for every $g\in G$ and $p(ge)=\mathcal{O}(ge)=\mathcal{O}(e)=p(e)$. Since e is projected injectively, the equation $ge=e$ must hold. So the relations $\mathcal{O}(e)=\{e\}$ and $Stab_G(e)=G$ must also hold. BUT, in most of the cases, the latter equality does NOT hold.

My only guess is that I haven't mastered what p actually does and what "injective" actually means. Thanks in advance and sorry for the long post.

Comment: Presumably you are assuming that $e \in T$ for some subtree $T$ of $X$ that projects injectively into $T'$. But that does not imply that $ge \in T$, so you cannot deduce that $ge=e$.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I noticed some minutes ago my mistake; when one says that a set is projected injectively in another subtree, it means that any couple of things IN THIS PARTICULAR SET is projected onto different elements. 

Actually at the time you posted the solution I was looking on if I can delete my question or if I should post the answer in the comments or answer section.

Thank you very much!